# M2 Edit mobile menu - remove 'All' keyword

Tags: magento-2.1, mobile-menu

In my mobile menu the first says "All Info" - see screenshot. How can I change this to simply "Info" and have the same font as "Sub Category 2" ?

[image]

Comment: Please provide code, without any code people wont be able to help you.

Comment: It's the standard code. Magento always put the word "All" in the front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`All` word is appended by `menu.js` located at `\vendor\magento\magento2-base\lib\web\mage\menu.js` line # 286 by following code :

```
...

this.categoryLink = $('<a>')
.attr('href', categoryUrl)
.text($.mage.__('All ') + category);

...
```

So you need to extend this js and update this code by :

```
...

this.categoryLink = $('<a>')
.attr('href', categoryUrl)
.text(category);

...
```

For Extending Magento 2 default JS components, check [this page](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/extending-magento-2-default-js-components/)

Comment: And how do I make the font the same as "Sub Category 2"?

Comment: If you have seen the next line of `menu.js`, there is a class added for it, i.e. `all-category`. You can do a CSS using this class